# Showing that $X^*$ has the same distribution as $X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a discrete random variable $X$ with probability function $$p_i=P(X=x_i), i=1,2,\ldots$$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}p_i=1$.  I need to generate $X^*$ such that $X^*$ has the same distribution as $X$.

We generated $X^*$ in the following way:
$$\begin{align}
b_0 &= 0 \\
b_1 &= p_1 \\
b_2 &= p_1 + p_2 \\
b_j &= p_1 + p_2 + \ldots + p_j \\
b_{\infty} &= \sum_{i}p_i = 1
\end{align}$$

and generating $R\sim U[0,1]$, the discrete uniform distribution over $U[0,1]$, if $b_{j-1} < R \leq b_j$.  Then we let $X^* = x_j$ and we have to show that $X^*$ has the same distribution as $X$.

So to show this, I have been trying to show that $P(X^*=x_j)=P(X=x_j)=p_j$.

I have that $X^*=x_j$ if $b_{j-1} < R \leq b_j$, so I rewrite $P(X^*=x_j)$ as $$
\begin{align}
P(b_{j-1} < R \leq b_j) &= P(R \leq b_j) - P(R<b_{j-1}) \\
&=F_R(b_j) - (F_R(b_{j-1}) - f_R(b_{j-1}))\\
&=\frac{\lfloor{b_j}\rfloor + 1}{2} - (\frac{\lfloor{b_{j-1}}\rfloor + 1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}) \\
&=\frac{\lfloor{b_j}\rfloor - \lfloor{b_{j-1}}\rfloor + 1}{2}
\end{align}$$

I'm not sure where to go from here, or if I'm even going in the right direction.

Comment: But you know what $P(R \leq b_j)$ is because $R$ is given to be uniform on $[0,1]$! Similarly for $R < b_{j-1}$. Simplify that.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I edited my original comment with further simplifications

Comment: no, R follows the uniform distribution which has $P(R \leq x) = x$ for every $x \in [0,1]$. Now the $b_j $ are in $[0,1]$. $R$ is not *discrete* uniform, because you cannot be discrete uniform over a countable set. If $R$ were discrete uniform, then the construction is not possible directly : you will have to get a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ using $R$, and substitute that here. I don't know how to do the first one, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate directly with pdf.

$$P(b_j<R\leq b_{j+1})=\int_{b_j}^{b_{j+1}} 1 dx = b_{j+1}-b_j=p_j$$

Comment: Doesn't $R$ follow a discrete uniform distribution, so we wouldn't be able to integrate

Comment: Oh oops, didnt notice that. However, your method as specifed won't work for any discrete X then. You need a genuine uniform distribution to do so. Also, how did you get 2 in the denominator of your cdf. Are you specifying that your discrete distribution R only takes two values?

Comment: I can explain further why a discrete uniform will not work how you want it to,  in a longer answer if you want.

Comment: So maybe I didn't fully understand the question.  In the question it says: "Generate $R$ from $U[0,1]$, the **discrete uniform distribution** over $[0,1]$. Let $X^*=x_j$ if $b_{j-1} < R \leq b_j$".  If we generate $R$ from the **discrete uniform distribution**, doesn't that mean $R$ can only take in 2 values, $0$ or $1$

Comment: Typically no. It is usually specified in advance how many values it will take. Is there a context to your question? The short answer would be to allow your discrete distribution to to take more values the more accurate you want to be. However, it could never be exact without being the genuine uniform distribution. Where are you getting the question from?

Comment: This problem is from some readings my professor gave out in my sampling theory class.  The title of the problem is called "Discrete Random Number Generator for Sample Selection"

Comment: Have you defined the discrete uniform distribution in class differently to the standard one?

Comment: No, I believe we did not define it differently